# How use array in text file text file (PHP)?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a txt file that contains an array like this:

```
array (
  0 => 'jack',
  1 => 'alex'
)
```

I want to use this array in my PHP code but it is not working as on this example which returns `a`

```
$list=  file_get_contents(myfile.txt); 
echo $list[0];
```

How  can I convert it ?

Comment: The array hasn't really been declared in myfile.txt. It's kinda' naked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather have the array `serialize`d or `json_encode`d, inside that file.
Then, when reading it, just `unserialize` or `json_decode` in `$list`

Example:

```
$list = unserialize(file_get_contents(myfile.txt));
```

Comment: with `unserialize` show this error `Notice: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 0 of 40 bytes` and with `json_decode` not show any thing

Comment: Make sure, the contents of `myfile.txt` is a serialized or json enconded array, otherwise, won't work

Comment: @user2511140, you can't just unserialize the current data in myfile.txt. You have to put a serialized array in myfile.txt. (User serialize on the array first, then put the output of that in myfile.txt)

Comment: Thanks @w0rldart. i use `json_encode` for write to file and use `json_decode` to for `$list` then problem solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the quextion - `eval` looks like it will handle the array (Array has been output with var_export ?)

BUT exec'ing unknown code is a bad idea, W0rldart has the better ways to do it (json would be my preference)

Comment: Don't you mean eval instead of exec?